# NPM CLI package.json invalid

Tags: node.js, npm

Before posting the issue, I surfed on all possible websites to fix the issue with Node.js- npm cli I am encountering. None of the answers worked for me and I got stuck with. Can someone help to fix it? 
The npm cli was running perfectly and it suddenly started to work giving me the traceback ***Please verify that the package.json has a valid 'main' entry***. Even if I re-installed the node.js it has not resolved the issue. (see screenshot below) 
The version node.js 16.17.1 on Windows 10

Screenshot:
[image]

The content of the package.json

```
{
  "name": "npm-bundled",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "list things in node_modules that are bundledDependencies, or transitive dependencies thereof",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/npm/npm-bundled.git"
  },
  "author": "Isaac Z. Schlueter <i@izs.me> (http://blog.izs.me/)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mutate-fs": "^1.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "tap": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tap test/*.js -J --100",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "postversion": "npm publish",
    "postpublish": "git push origin --all; git push origin --tags"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-normalize-package-bin": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

AKA

Comment: You should look into `package.json`. You should also include the file contents here

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Please have a look at content of the package json. I added it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]:**
Thanks everyone. The problem was lying in the directory *C:\Users\your_comp_name\AppData\Local\node* & *C:\Users\your_comp_name\AppData\Roaming\npm* that only needs to be removed to run npm cli further.